# responding to post from jquery to rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jeditable

Apologies for the bad wording of the question but its pretty straight forward.

I'm sending some paramaters across to the rails application as such

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("testing!@£");
    $('.editable-td').editable(home_address, {
        data   : " {'E':'Letter E','F':'Letter F','G':'Letter G', 'selected':'F'}",
        type      : 'textarea',
        cancel    : 'Cancel',
        submit    : 'OK',
        tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
    });
});
```

When the rails app receives the params, I'd like to respond back with the text that was passed in. Otherwise after you submit the data to the rails server, the textarea you updated will revert to its previous state.

def update
    puts params
    @response = (params[:value])
    puts "NOWWHATSHOULDIDO"

```
   respond_to do |format|
      if params
        format.json { head :ok }
#         respond with the variable  @response here
      else
        format.json  { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

---

a small attempt:

```
 def update
    puts params

    puts "NOWWHATSHOULDIDO"

    respond_to :json
    if params
      respond_with(params) do |format|
        format.json { render }
      end
    end
  end
```

Another small attempt is here which responds to the user but the jeditable area shows up as null. Any ideas?

```
 def update
    puts params
    @x = (params[:values])
    render :json => @x.to_json
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first you could, I believe you could do:

```
render :text => params[:value], :status => :ok
```